# HP MSA2000, how detect faulty disks?

Tags: storage, hp, storage-area-network, hp-modular-smart-array

I have an HP MSA2012fc, it happened a few times that my large vdisk (6x 1TB raid 5) get offline, seems some disks are faulty, the event log only shows 2 of the drives had "bad blocks" and some disk read errors are reported in event log, and some other disk get into left over state with no error log by those two. can any one suggest how to scan all drives for defects and replacement to prevent future loss?

Comment: Check the logs for the Device ID's of the failed disks. The slots run 1 to 12 Drive ID's run 0 to 11

Answer (score 1):

Your MSA2012/P2000 SAN should have a scheduled background "scrub" process enabled. If not, it can be run manually by choosing a *vdisk* and selecting the "*Media Scrub Vdisk.*" option.

As for notification, configure the email notification settings on the array. That's the best way to obtain fault information from the unit.

Comment: yeah the scrub is already running, but although I have only "Disk detected error" for two disk, but it happened two times that the vdisk came down and some other disks get into leftover state. do you think only removing those two disk with error reports is sufficient? and isnt there a more accurate test than "scrub" ?

Comment: Beyond that, if you're still having problems, I'd reach out to HP support. You don't have to have an active support contract to get them to address this issue. It could be a firmware or software release problem as well.

Comment: good idea, I try the HP support if they help without support contract. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try booting from the HP Smart Start DVD and run the long disk diagnostic utility to test all disks if you can afford server/storage downtime.

Comment: Why would that detect disk faults on an external SAN?

Comment: There is an option for running the utility with FC enabled, allowing you access to remote disks.

Comment: can HP smart start scan all the disks in this way? or only those in accessible vdisks to that server?